# Como inserir numa base de dados com caracteres especiais?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou a fazer o seguinte `INSERT`:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_livro VALUES (NULL, '$titulo', '$autor_livro')");
```

O que acontece é que existem autores que tem o nomes com caracteres especiais, por exemplo: **O'Reilly Media, Inc.**

O que acontece é que a `'` faz conflito na inserção.

Existe alguma maneira de ignorar os caracteres especiais que estão dentro da variável `$autor_livro`? O objetivo é inserir com os caracteres especiais.

Nota: eu sei que devia usar `mysqli` ou `PDO` mas neste exemplo tem que ser mesmo em `mysql`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É necessário escapar os caracteres especiais na sua query.

No seu caso, use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

```
$titulo = mysql_real_escape_string($titulo);
$autor_livro = mysql_real_escape_string($autor_livro);
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_livro VALUES (NULL, '$titulo', '$autor_livro')");
```

**Ressalvando:** Esse é um caso que vale muito mais a pena utilizar `Mysqli` ou `PDO`. Ambos suportam [*prepared statements*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) e você não teria esse tipo de problemas ao inserir parâmetros em sua consulta.

Exemplo do uso de *prepared statements* com PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_livro VALUES (NULL, :titulo, :autor_livro)");
$stmt->bindParam(':titulo', $titulo);
$stmt->bindParam(':autor_livro', $autor_livro);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: O AP já fez a ressalva na pergunta.

Comment: @JorgeB. vou incluir um exemplo extra de como prepared statements podem ajudar nossa vida caso alguém veja a pergunta no futuro.

Comment: mas o meu objectivo é inserir com os caracteres especiais, o  mysql_real_escape_string permite isso?

Comment: @pc_oc sim, é exatamente isso que essa função faz.

Comment: obrigado @gmsantos. Infelizmente neste projecto tenho que usar mysql e não PDO. obrigado